# Why does my Gatsby.js build generate duplicate data for each post?

Tags: javascript, gatsby

My gatsby.js site is based off the repo used by egghead.io: [gatsby-starter-egghead-blog](https://github.com/eggheadio/gatsby-starter-egghead-blog/)

When I run a `gatsby build` command I get the following file structure generated (I've omitted the 404 and index folders)

[image]

For each blog post in my "content" folder I get 2 folders generated each with the same name as the blog post.  The one under "public" contains an html file and the one under "page-data" contains a json file containing the exact same content as that rendered in the html file minus any CSS styling.

Why do these json files exist when I already have static html files?  Essentially I'm getting duplicate data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I just found the answer to this.

Gatsby.js follows the [PRPL](https://web.dev/apply-instant-loading-with-prpl/) Pattern.

The first page you visit for any Gatsby site loads a static HTML page.  Any subsequent page visits behave more like an SPA.  You can see this if you watch the network tab in Chrome while browsing a Gatsby site.  First the HTML page is loaded and after that, as you navigate the site, the pages are loaded from the page-data.json files.

The implementation of this pattern by Gatsby is described in more detail [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/prpl-pattern/).

This explains why the data for each page exists twice in a Gatsby site - as rendered static HTML for first load and as raw JSON data to be loaded dynamically.